# $5^x \equiv 1520 \pmod {9797}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

How do you solve this? What does mod mean and how will I solve it? I understand that it can be solved but how? 5 to some exponent equals the (mod of 9797) what is the answer to this?

Comment: one solution is $$x=26$$

Comment: "mod" means you need to find $x$ so that $5^x-1520$ is divisible by $9797$

Comment: $\equiv$ is not an equal sign. $\pmod{9797}$ belongs to that and together they mean that the two ides of the $\equiv$ have the same remainder on division by $9797$.

Comment: Can u solve this equation and tell me what's the anwser

Comment: What background can you use to solve it?  What is the name of the class?

Comment: Somebody already told you $x=26$ satisfies this equation.

Comment: [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5%5Ex+mod+9797+%3D+1520+modulo+9797+) gives $x=2(1200n+13)$ works for any $n\ge 0$.

Comment: As pointed out above, the operation $ a \operatorname{mod} b$ means taking the least non-negative remainder when dividing $a$ by $b$. So, e.g. $10 \operatorname{mod} 2$ is 0, because 10 is divisible by 2 without any remainder. As @Henrik said before, we don't use $=$ sign in case of an equation, because the two sides of the equation are not really equal, but give the same remainder after the division (we say they are _congruent_). E.g. $4 \equiv 10\,(\operatorname{mod} 2)$, $5 \equiv 29\,(\operatorname{mod} 6), \ldots$

Comment: it is $26$ what i have already posted

Comment: $9797 = 101 \cdot 97$ so use the chinese remainder theorem

Comment: Can u show me how u solved it to get 26?

Comment: I want to tell everyone thank u for that Anwser it's correct